# Allow all types of elements and Attributes in Tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

How to allow all custom user defined elements and attribute in tinymce editor. I am using below code buts its inserting my span element but removing temp attribute. Can it possible that tinymce allow all custom attributes and elements in it?

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 
    "<span class=\"fnlabel\"  temp=\"footnote\">" + labelText + "</span> "
);
```

Comment: In the future, please do some research, at the very least reading the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My requirement is to enable all custom element andywhere in body action. But tinymce is just removing those on saving and inserting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the extended_valid_elements in your editor configuration:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#extended_valid_elements

Comment: There is nothing like extended_valid_attributes

Comment: It is colled extended_valid_elements (See link) (and I will update the answer)

Comment: yes i have already seen this. But this is not allowing all my custom attributes. My custom attributes can be inside any tag in tinymce editor.

Comment: Just one thing. I am to add custom attributes and element by using below config. But its removing my temp attribute when i am using mceinertcommand.

Comment: valid_elements: '*[*]',
        menubar: "table",
        extended_valid_elements: 'body[*]',
        extended_valid_attributes:'*[*]',